# Retrive file name from database using HttpHandlers

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, ihttphandler

I have database with EmpNo(Int) and EmpImage(Image) columns.

I am using HttpHandler to display the Images.

I am storing Images both in database and folder.

Now I want to change the names of Images in folder as names of EmpNo whose I didn't change while uploading.

So need to fetch the Images names from database to compare them with the Image names in the folder and rename them.

How can i fetch or extract the image names from the binary data that i get from database using generic handler.

I have attached the code In handler for reference.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class Lab_14___ImageFetchingHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        SqlConnection vConn = new SqlConnection("server=localhost; database=Asp.netDemoWebsiteDatabase; Integrated Security = SSPI;");
        vConn.Open();
        String vQuery = "Select EmpImage from EmpImages where Empno=@id";
        SqlCommand vComm = new SqlCommand(vQuery, vConn);

        //Receive the Id from some Form
        String vId = context.Request.QueryString["id"];
        vComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", vId);
        SqlDataReader vDr = vComm.ExecuteReader();
        while (vDr.Read())
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])vDr["EmpImage"]);

            [ Here I need the Images names to store in List or array.How?? ]
        }
        vConn.Close();
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Image name is not captured with the binary data stored in Database, it is just binary data. You have to capture and save image name into a separate column while uploading. That way when you retrieve image content from database, you also have the name handy.

Comment: Can you upload a test project for me to inspect?

Comment: Ha, Vinod I removed my comment Because I found out I was wrong and my statement was wrong. It dosent display any file name. It is just converting the binary data into image. I was thinking if file is converted to binary then the name will be also converted to binary because it is the part of the file. Am I right?

Comment: yes, the name is not preserved with meta data. you just have to capture it when the file is getting uploaded. If the below answer was any helpful, please upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are different ways to inspect image metadata.

```
Byte[] content = (Byte[])vDr["EmpImage"]

//Option 1
Image img = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(content));
Encoding _Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

var props = img.PropertyItems;
string propData;
foreach (var propertyItem in props)
{
    propData = _Encoding.GetString(propertyItem.Value);
    Debug.WriteLine("{0}[{1}]", propertyItem.Id, propData);
}

//option 2 - require reference of PresentationCore and WindowsBase and then using System.Windows.Media.Imaging
var imgFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(new MemoryStream(content));
var metadata = imgFrame.Metadata as BitmapMetadata;

//option 3 - require MetadataExtractor Nuget package
var mr = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(new MemoryStream(content));
foreach (var directory in mr)
{
    foreach (var tag in directory.Tags)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("{0} - {1} = {2}]", directory.Name, tag.Name, tag.Description);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nithin - Please upload a test project that I can inspect to see why and how are seeing the file name when you right click and select View Image. Which browser are you using to test?